# String.format doesn't give month and weeknames in German locale

Tags: android, date, localization, format

I'm using following code in my app:

```
Calendar tmpCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
String itemTime = String.format(
        Locale.getDefault(),
        "%1$tA, %1$te. %1$tB %1$tY",
        tmpCalendar);
```

German is the default language on my device, so I'd expect to get something like:

> Dienstag, 7. Juni 2011

Instead I'm getting:

> 3, 7. 6 2011

If I use `Locale.US` instead of `Locale.getDefault()` everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Oddly, it works in an emulator running Android 2.2 in German, but not on a HTC Desire, also running 2.2. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of some vendors and is [issue #9453 in the Android issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9453).

Comment: This is not a bug; the device doesn't support the selected locale. Try it for yourself: `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` won't contain the German locale. You either need to provide the month and weekday names manually, or cope with the fact that not all devices are created equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String sDate= sdf.format(date);
```

Read more on it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: i wrote an update. it works on emulator, but not on device :(

Comment: The `EE` gave me a short written day like "di". When I made it `EEEE` it wrote "dinsdag"

Comment: look at my answer. it seems to be a bug on my device

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you ask it to do. If you want to have fine-grain control over the process, you can always use SimpleDateFormat. However, I would rather recommend this method:

```
Calendar tmpCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String itemTime = formatter.format(tmpCalendar.getTime());
```

Also, I would recommend using DateFormat.DEFAULT but you expect long date format, so...

Comment: I must admit I was not aware of it.